# How to dynamically change Date Box Mode based on device

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I want to show a device specific date picker using the JQM Datebox plugin.

The AngularJS View by default contains Date Box mode option as - "datebox". 
Then if device is iPhone, it should be changed to 'flipbox'.

Using following piece of code which is not working:

```
$("#Date1").data('options', '{"mode": "flipbox", "useNewStyle":true}')
$('#Date1').trigger('datebox', { 'method': 'dorefresh' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is a jsFiddle with the mode switch:  **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/2ffpP/**

In markup  I created the date input with a mode of datebox.

```
<input name="Date1" id="Date1" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox"}' />
```

Then in code within the pageinit switch the mode with $('element').datebox({opt, value}) (api doc here: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/api/events.html

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page1', function () {
    //check if iOS, if true run next line
    $('#Date1').datebox({"mode": "flipbox"});
});
```

In the fiddle I also included a couple of buttons to toggle the mode back and forth...

Comment: Thanks ezanker. You saved lots of my time.